Function parameter type which depends on type of another parameter using conditional types
Here:
function foo<T extends boolean> ( multiple: T,  value: T extends true ? number[] : number) {
  if (multiple) {
    let test: number[] =  value; //   Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.(2322)

  }

 
}

I was expecting inside if, value to be resolved as number[] no?

Initially had tried without generics too but had same issues:
function foo ( multiple: boolean,  value: typeof multiple extends true ? number[] : number) {
  if (multiple) {
    let test: number[] =  value; //   Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.(2322)

  }

 
}


couldn't you just say T is number | number[] and then verify in the function block if it's an array or not?

@Icepickle You are basically suggesting to get rid of the multiple param and also generics I suppose and do: value: number| number[]?

This question is similar to: Types narrowing with generics. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The generic is rather useless since it could always be instantiated to boolean anyway. I would suggest you use overloading instead, or even get rid of the multiple parameter altogether and just check Array.isArray(value).

@Bergi "The generic is rather useless since it could always be instantiated to boolean anyway." Can you elaborate a bit?

I mean that it allows not only foo<false>(false, 5) and foo<true>(true, []) but also foo<false | true>(true, 5).

@Bergi Ah inside the conditional type TS will think T is false | true instead of true which was passed as parameter and allow 5 that is what you mean hm..

@Bergi Any idea why my second version wasn't working (without generics)?

typeof multiple is the same as writing boolean

Use generics like in your first code snippet. It's not useless in your usecase. T will be inferred from the passed argument for multiple and give you type hinting for value. That's useful. Since you can't narrow value with control flow (your if block), just add an array check in the if the if statement. if (multiple && Array.isArray(value){}. It feels redundant, but go with it until the TS issues in the duplicate I linked are resolved.

Yes you can callfoo<true|false>(), But that's not your use case, the point is to infer T as either true or false by passing an argument for multiple and then narrowing value based on that.

@Brother58697 Thanks but I am not sure what you were trying to say in the last comment: "Yes you can foo<true|false>()"?

From what I skimmed through the comments, Bergi pointed out that passing true|false for T makes it so that you can pass the "wrong" type to value. And that you shouldn't use generics because of it. I'm saying that this won't affect you since that's not your use case, AKA just don't pass a type for T and let it be inferred from multiple

@Brother58697 I see. I thought bergi's point about true|false was more about explanation why TS can't narrow the generic in this case

Ahh, if that's the case I must have misunderstood.

(try foo(Math.random()<0.99,1)) TS lacks features you need for this to work with generics; notably ms/TS#27808 and ms/TS#33912. If the return type of foo doesn't depend on the input, then you can rewrite this using destructuring assignment of a discriminated union rest parameter as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a suitable duplicate. If not, what am I missing?

@jcalz Actually I notice I was not exact because my original use case was that foo was a react component, so I think the solution in that case looks like this: foo({multiple,value}:   ({ multiple: true; value: number[] } | { multiple: false; value: number })) ? because react props are wrapped inside object.  There could be other props too beside these two.

Feel free to do that. Does this change anything about the question as asked? Should I go ahead and write my answer?

@jcalz It is same question just in react those function arguments are wrapped inside object like in my above example. You can write answer for my original question, and mention react use case as extra.

I don't know anything about react and the question as asked doesn't mention it, so I'm not going to put that in my answer. What should I do here?

@jcalz I don't know the way it is asked now as I realized is not useful for my use case because in my case it is wrapped inside object like I wrote above. So I am thinking maybe deleting this question is the way to go...

You're going to delete the question? I'm so confused. Stack Overflow questions aren't just for the asker, they're also for future readers. Are you saying you can't figure out how to adapt my answer to your use case? Or you somehow need the question to either be deleted or represent your particular use case exactly? I have never used react so I cannot talk about react in my answer.  If you want to change the question to be about objects instead of parameter lists, you can do that, and I'll answer that question. Or if you want to delete the q that's your prerogative, I guess?

@jcalz Ok you can answer the original question if there are no duplicates (there was one duplicate suggested above but it does not contain the answer with the tuples you mention here) and maybe someone will find it useful in the future.

TypeScript can't currently mix generics with control flow analysis very well. When you check multiple, TypeScript can narrow multiple from T to, say, T & true. But it cannot narrow or re-constrain T itself. You'd like to say that if multiple is true then T must also be true.  But that's actually not the case, as you can verify by calling:
foo(Math.random() < 0.99, 1); // no compiler error, 99% chance of failure

Here Math.random() < 0.99 is of type boolean which is the union type true | false, so the distributive conditional type T extends true ? number[] : number evaluates to the union number[] | number, and suddenly foo() accepts possibly mismatched arguments.
There is a longstanding open feature request at microsoft/TypeScript#27808 to allow someone to have a generic function where T is either true or false and cannot be the union true | false. But for now it's not part of the language.  Additionally there's the general problem whereby TypeScript really can't see if some value is or is not assignable to a generic conditional type. The feature request at microsoft/TypeScript#33912 deals with that. Until and unless these are implemented, you'll have to change what you're doing.

In general the only surefire way to work around this is with type assertions. But in this case your function's return type does not depend on its input (it's always void) and the argument list looks like a discriminated union [true, number[]] | [false, number] because true and false are valid discriminants.
So you can refactor your code to use control flow analysis instead of generics. The function can accept a rest parameter whose type is a destructured discriminated union of tuple types:
function foo(...[multiple, value]:
    [multiple: true, value: number[]] |
    [multiple: false, value: number]
) {
    if (multiple) {
        let test: number[] = value; // okay
    }
}

That works because TypeScript now understands that checking multiple will narrow the discriminated union represented by [multiple, value].  When you call foo() it looks like an overloaded function:
foo(^
// 1/2 foo(multiple: true, value: number[]): void
// 2/2 foo(multiple: false, value: number): void

And you can call it in the ways you want
foo(true, [1, 2, 3]);
foo(false, 4);

And if you call it in invalid ways you get an error, even in the Math.random() case:
foo(true, 5); // error
foo(Math.random() < 0.99, 1); //error

That's because [boolean, number] is not assignable to [true, number[]] | [false, number].
Playground link to code
